# What makes unorder_map and unorder_set faster than map and set?

Tags: c++, containers

So, yesterday I had a lecture about STL Associative Containers (unordered_map, unordered_set, map and set). The lector told us that usually unordered_map and unordered_set are 0(1) and map and set are 0(log(N)). My question is what makes them faster? They are not sorted after all.

Comment: Look up hash-maps.

Comment: Did you have a course on data structures yet? You need to understand how [*binary tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and [*hash table*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) work to understand the difference in time complexity.

Comment: Exactly that. You trade the possibility to iterate them in order for faster, on average, insertion and lookup.

Comment: @bipll `unordered_map::iterator` is a thing. I think you mean "iterate them *in a particular order*"

Comment: @Caleth in order of keys, eh?

Comment: @bipll No, i mean that the order that `std::unordered_set<int> set {1, 2, 3}; std::copy(set.begin(), set.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));` prints may change from run to run

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I'm saying, desu ka?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying data structure used to represent these containers is what makes one efficient over the other.

- unordered_map and unordered set use a hash table
- map and set use a self balancing BST (Binary Search Tree)

Hash tables usually has a O(1) insertion, search time. Hash tables achieve this because they use an indexed approach to access and store data.

Where as the BST's are O(log(n)) primarily because of the traversal involved in searching or inserting to the tree. They don't use indexed approach. For any operation you start from the root node and then traverse.